# mex functions could not be resolved eclipse

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, matlab, mex

I am trying to compile c++ code (which contain mex function like: mxGetNumberOfElement, mxCreateDoubleScalar,mxArray etc.) on eclipse (linux).

I followed this instructions to [configure](http://ninghang.blogspot.co.il/2012/04/configure-eclipse-to-build-mex.html) eclipse.

But unfortunately I got this errors:

```
function 'mxGetNumberOfElements' could not be resolved.
function 'mxGetNumberOfElements' could not be resolved.
function 'mxCreateDoubleScalar' could not be resolved.
....
```

What am I missing?

How can I configure Eclipse to recognize this functions?

My code is very similar to the code in Matlab examples:

```
arrayProduct.c
```

Which is under "Create C Source MEX-File" in this [site](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/standalone-example.html).

I already compile My code in Visual Studio on Windows and it worked, 
but I need to work on linux.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I guess in step 3 you didn't find the correct path to your installation of matlab.

Comment: Are you talking about adding "/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnx86" to the library path? I already did it.

Comment: If the path doesn't work, try explicitly specify those three library files to the linker.

Answer (score 0):

*The following instructions are the lengthy version of this [blog entry](http://ninghang.blogspot.de/2012/04/configure-eclipse-to-build-mex.html).*

Assuming your Matlab installation resides in `MATLABPATH`, the following steps enable you to have MEX functions compiled in Eclipse:

1. Go to *Project settings > C/C++ Build > Settings > Build Artifact*.

   - From the drop down menu *Artifact Type*, choose *Shared Library*.
   - Enter the desired name of your MEX function in the text field *Artifact name*.
   - As an artifact extension, choose `mexa64` into the corresponding text field.
   - Choose the *Output prefix* to be empty.
2. Go to *Project settings > C/C++ Build > Settings > Tool Settings*.

   - In the left navigation pane, go to *GCC C Compiler > Includes*.
   - To the right, there's a (presumably empty) list of *Include paths*, click on the *Add...* symbol (sheet of paper with a green `+').
   - The *Add directory path* dialogue box opens. Click on the *File system..* button and go to directory `MATLABPATH/extern/include`. Click *OK*.
   - In the left navigation pane, go to *GCC C Linker > Libraries*.
   - To the right, there's a list of *Libraries*. Add one.
   - The *Enter Value* dialogue box opens. Enter `mex`.
   - Add another library called `mat`...
   - ...and a last one named `mx`.
   - To the right, there's also a *Library search path* list. Add one.
   - The *Add directory path* dialogue box opens. Click on the *File system..* button and go to directory `MATLABPATH/bin/glnxa64`. Click *OK*.
   - In the left navigation pane, go to *GCC C Compiler > Miscellaneous*.
   - Activate the option *Position Independent Code (-fPIC)*.

Done. You can now compile MEX files in Eclipse.
The following code should compile to a MEX function that returns the root of a real, scalar, double input value:

```
#include "mex.h"

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[]) {

    nlhs = 1;
    mxArray* arg[1];
    *arg = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1,1,mxREAL);
    mxSetPr(*arg,mxGetPr(*prhs));

    mexCallMATLAB(1,plhs,1,arg,"sqrt");

}
```

The compiled code, i.e. the MEX function, can be found in Eclipse's workspace:
`/home/your_initials/workspace/project_name/Debug/name_of_mex_function`.

---

*Versions used:*
Eclipse (Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)) 
Linux: 4.3.3-2-ARCH (64-bit)
Matlab: R2015a
gcc: 5.3.0