# How can I compile a mex function in Windows with Eclipse (4.20.0 version) and Matlab (R2021a)

Tags: c++, eclipse, function, matlab, mex

I'm trying to compile a c++ mex function that I created according to the specifications given by mathworks [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/c-mex-source-file.html) (Create a C++ MEX Source File). However, after following the steps of the answer in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28214068/mex-functions-could-not-be-resolved-eclipse) to link Eclipse 4.4.2 and Matlab R2015a in a linux enviroment (old but the only one I've found about it), I get the following error:

```
undefined reference to `get_function_ptr'   mpi_pevd_mex_f      line 79, external location: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2021a\extern\include\MatlabDataArray\detail\ExceptionHelpers.hpp   C/C++ Problem
```

I don't know what else is missing. I've been trying to find a solution, but nothing useful so far.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I guess you need to "link" the necessary library.

Comment: (1) In the title you say "Windows", in the body of the question you say "Linux". Please be clear about what system you are on. (2) With "Eclipse" you mean the IDE? (3) You should use the `mex` command to build your MEX-file, because setting all the right variables and options manually is quite hard. (4) If you followed instructions for Linux on a Windows machine, you must adapt the specified paths, and not only replacing `glnxa64` with whatever the Windows version is. MATLAB on Windows stores libraries in different places than on Windows.

Comment: Also, running `mex` with the `-v` option will show all the compiler settings it uses to build your MEX-file. You could try copying those over into Eclipse. The Q&A you linked tries to set up Eclipse for a C MEX-file, not C++. The C++ API didn't exist when that Q&A was written.

Comment: @CrisLuengo 1) I'm using windows. In the body, I was just specifying that the instructions I followed from the Q&A were for Linux. 2) Yes, I'm talking about Eclipse IDE 3) I'm using also the mex command in Matlab, but I'd like to debug the function from Eclipse instead of setting up flags in the code and guessing where it crashes. 4) I'm sure the Paths are ok, I have doubts about the rest of the settings. For instance, I found that the artifact extension should be mexw64 for windows, instead of mexa64; but I don't know if another setting should be changed or not.

Comment: Maybe this is of use: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/debugging-on-microsoft-windows-platforms.html

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thank you! I had already checked that. I guess that if there's no solution to my problem with Eclipse I'll change to Visual Studio or continue working just with Matlab.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the problem. Apparently, I needed to add additional libraries to those detailed in most of the posts related to MEX files, i.e. libmex/ libmat/libmx.

Making use of the verbose mode in Matlab (mex -v MexFunction.cpp), I realized that these libraries were missing: libmwlapack, m, libmwblas, libMatlabEngine, libMatlabDataArray. After adding them, the error disappeared.

Comment: `libMatlabEngine` is never used by MEX-files, it is only needed by applications that use the MATLAB Engine to control MATLAB. `libMatlabDataArray` is needed only if you use the new C++ API, which you do, and I presume that this is the one library that you were missing. The LAPACK and BLAS libraries are used by MATLAB, but you shouldn't need to link explicitly to them, unless you directly call functions in there. The `m` library is for math functions, most programs need to link to that.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Is there a reason why Matlab includes all those libraries when compiling with the mex command?

Comment: It is easier I guess to link to everything rather than trying to figure out which ones are needed.